# Sublime text suddenly started adding spaces to my snippet

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

when i do

```
w + tab
```

it gives me

```
<?php echo $jd['  ']; ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $jd[' ']; ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php echo $jd['']; ?>
```

yesterday i didn't have this problem

snippet code:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<?php echo \$jd['${1:}']; ?>
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>w</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

Comment: Unable to replicate. Any chance it is an issue with your keyboard or similar?

Comment: Yes this can be possible, thanks anyways